# what is the order of calculating i+v[i++]

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        cout << i+v[i++] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why the output of the program is "2,4,6,8,10", instead of "1,3,5,7,9"?

Comment: `Why the output of the program is "2,4,6,8,10", instead of "1,3,5,7,9"` Undefined behavior.

Comment: To expand on what @kiranBiradar says, you *aren't allowed* to do this expression. It'll compile, but the compiler can do whatever it wants. It'll probably try to do something sensible, but it might not be a good judge what "sensible" is, so you should avoid undefined behavior in almost all cases.

Comment: @DanielH Thanks for your extended explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because the read of the "first" `i` and the other `i++` are *unsequenced*. The output is meaningless.

Further reading: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points),

Answer (score 5):

Some compilers will warn you that you are doing something that leads to undefined behavior: Relying on the evaluation order of unsequenced expressions.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/fWbzdT):

> ```
> <source>:22:22: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]
>    cout << i+v[i++] << endl;
> ```

The evaluation order of expressions between [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) is not defined. The only sequence point in the expression `i+v[i++]` is at the end of the expression, so the compiler is free to order the addition of `i` and the increment of `i` however it wants.